# Communication among C# client and browser

Tags: javascript, c#, phantomjs, webrtc

Hey Guys I am working on webrtc to make data communication between two client. Now the problem is one of the client is C#. I tried to embed some native library provided by mesh central.com but it didn't worked for me.

I also tried to embed headless browser in c# app like phantom and selenium. But these browser doesn't supports webrtc.

I am just guessing is there really any way we can communicate among c# app and browser using webrtc. Please suggest some way of it's possible.

Comment: doesn't make sense. webRTC is peer to peer and a server does not get in middle of the data transfer between peers. Sounds more like you are looking for websockets

Comment: It does actually. For e.g application that built on Wpf want to make communication with some SPA then we can leverage webrtc as communication technology.

Comment: What does that have to do with server-client?

Comment: Where u got this "server-client". ? I am talking to make communication among c# (as native app) and browser. Btw we can also built native app using WPF.

Comment: Ok...starting to understand. You would probably need to embed a browser like chrome that supports webRTC

Comment: Yup.. that's wht I tried to use cefsharp and phantomjs. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should use chromium browser using CefSharp library, it supports WebRTC, but you should first enable some settings on the chromium using Cef command line arguments like "enable-media-stream".

Comment: I have just read that you have used chromium but with no luck. So can you tell us what kind of problems you had with CefSharp so we can try to help you.

Comment: you should comment on the question not on your answer

Comment: I know, but I am still not able to add comments to others' posts.